# Can my DVD burner write "Dual Layer" disks?

Tags: windows, optical-drive, dvd-burning

Is there a generic way to find out if a DVD burner can burn dual layer DVD’s without trying and potential waste a disk?

Right now it’s [this drive](http://www.cdrinfo.com/Sections/Reviews/Specific.aspx?ArticleId=25053) I’m wondering about but I'd like a solution that works for all/most DVD drives out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Nero Info Tool](http://www.nero.com/enu/support-nero8-tools-utilities.html) can show you the capabilities of your DVD drive. Look for the DVD +R DL and DVD -R DL options.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to install the software, you can add an underscore (_) at the end of the link (.zip_ instead of .zip), download it, and after that remove the underscore to have a zip file.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to check is the front bezel of the drive: more often than not you will find some indication under or next to any logo that is on there.

There are a number of tools out there that interrogate your drives to see what capabilities they have. Nero's [infotool](http://www.nero.com/enu/support-nero8-tools-utilities.html) is one of the better freely available ones (it is included as part of their paid for apps, but can be downloaded separately for free). It gives this sort of output:

[image]